# Make section border/separator invisible in list form body custom layout with JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

I have a form section that has 4 fields to it, but we would prefer to have these 4 fields organized in 2 rows and 2 columns, rather than to flex, which ends up as 1 row with 4 columns.

A simple work around was to split the section into 2, with the second having a blank title. However there is still a separator (horizontal line) between the 2 of them, is there a way to get rid of this or make it invisible? Or perhaps some other way to accomplish this?

Here's an image that might explain it better:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, removing separator/line is *not possible* using JSON formatting capabilities.

> Unlike the header and the footer, body configuration **only allows defining one or more sections** and adding one or more columns into each of those sections.

Body configuration does not support advance JSON customizations like header/footer (or column/view formatting in list views).

**Source**: [Configure custom body with one or more sections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration#configure-custom-body-with-one-or-more-sections)